# Check if a username exists in facebook page follower list using facebook-graph-api

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I want to check if a username is present in my company's facebook page using facebook graph api version 17.0.

I tried below things:

1. https://graph.facebook.com/v17.0/page-id/followers?access_token=your-access-token -This gave me error
   {
   "error": {
   "message": "(#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (followers) on node type (Page)",
   "type": "OAuthException",
   "code": 100,
   "fbtrace_id": "A866wNdB0Zq-k5kJNn0K_AW"
   }
   }
2. https://graph.facebook.com/v17.0/page-id/likes?access_token=your-access-token - This gave me error
   {
   "error": {
   "message": "Permissions error",
   "type": "OAuthException",
   "code": 200,
   "error_subcode": 2069033,
   "is_transient": false,
   "error_user_title": "Unavailable Feature On New Page Experience",
   "error_user_msg": "The corresponding UI feature of this API is deprecated or not available for the new Pages experience.",
   "fbtrace_id": "AuYuVDh7nb_KjrZSYWWWbC6"
   }
   }
3. https://graph.facebook.com/v17.0/page-id?fields=followers_count?access_token=your-access-token - This gave me output with number of followers
   {
   "followers_count": 8,
   "id": "XXXXX"
   }

Is there any way or any permission I need to request to check if a given usename is preset in my company facebook page follower list using facebook graph api version17.0

Comment: Not sure if there currently is any valid way. And following and liking are two different things, if you are interested in the latter, and the user grants your app `user_likes` permission, then you could determine it via the `likes` edge of the user. (What do you need this for? Rewarding users in any way for liking your page, is not allowed ...)